# matching element of one list to each element of another list to detect a match/mismatch. List of strings, using Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

```
In[49]:= table
OpenRead["Desktop/SAP-MSBG Univ Coimbra/Mathematica/selorg.txt"]

Out[49]= InputStream["Desktop/SAP-MSBG Univ \
Coimbra/Mathematica/selorg.txt", 94]

In[50]:= table2 = 
OpenRead["H:\\SAP-MSBG Univ Coimbra\\Mathematica\\Missing PEP \
files.txt"]

Out[50]= InputStream["H:\\SAP-MSBG Univ Coimbra\\Mathematica\\Missing \
PEP files.txt", 95]

In[51]:= data = ReadList[table, String];

In[52]:= removaldata = ReadList[table2, String];
```

Now both lists are string lists and 'removaldata' is a subset of 'data'. How can I produce a list containing the elements exclusive to data. I have tried using loops and conditionals, but they did not yield any result.

Comment: It would help to have a (small) sample of your lists.

Comment: In[3]:= removaldata = ReadList[table2, String]

Out[3]= {"a.actinomycetemcomitans.pep", "a.degensii.pep", \
"a.fermentans.pep", "a.macleodii.pep", "a.marginale_florida.pep"}

Comment: I have only printed a part of the list,  both lists have elements like the afore mentioned.

Comment: Maybe `Complement[data, removaldata ]` ?